# react-native iOS Build Release impossible because of architecture i386

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I'm programming an react-native app for iPad, it was eject from expo. After some fix, I can run it without problem in Debug/Dev mode (from bash or xcode) on simulator and device (iPad 6).
I'm trying now to build it in Release mode and it always failed.

On Xcode, I have the following errors :

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

and

> ignoring file /Users/pierrefournier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gazecraftclient-ckrnxvomxhpaiwbgwxgizparpugq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/gazecraftclient.app/gazecraftclient, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/pierrefournier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gazecraftclient-ckrnxvomxhpaiwbgwxgizparpugq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/gazecraftclient.app/gazecraftclient

My package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.3.4",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.4",
    "react-native-canvas": "0.1.31",
    "react-native-pdf": "^5.0.11",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.3.5",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15",
    "victory-native": "^31.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.8.8",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.41"
}
```

Xcode : 10.1
Node : 11.13.0
macOS : 10.14.1

I tried to regenerate iOS folder, nothing change. 
I have JavaScriptCore.framework in linked frameworks.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click your project on the left side, select your Target, then choose build-setting, under Dead Code Stripping > Release, select "No".

Hope It may work!

Comment: It doesn't change anything :/ I have the same error